# How to create date dimension with decades in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, olap, olap-cube

I want to create a date dimension for an OLAP cube, which have to use Russian dates format and include decades (like 80s, 90s, etc.).
How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

in your table design, do you have a Date dimension? If so, you can add another field to it for the decade and update the field data accordingly for the dates you have in the table. That would be an ideal approach so that you can use it for many other things. OLAP cube is anyway taking the data from these tables right, So i think it is a good way of doing it.